# Treeview in webpage , mongodb as datasource

Tags: php, mongodb, html

I've an database, where one column contains file path. I would like to showcase the path information as treeview in webpage.

I use mongodb and php..

Comment: Can you give one example of path structure?

Comment: path : /tmp/file1/file.txt

Answer (score 0):

This might be your php code:

```
<?php
// Establish your connection
$con = new MongoClient();
// Select Database
if($con){
    $db = $con->db_name;
    // Select Collection
    $collection = $db->coll_name;

    $qry = array(/*Your query here*/), array("file_path"=>1);

    $result = $collection->findOne($qry);

    if(!empty($result)){
        $fp = $result['file_path'];
        $fp_arr = explode("/", $fp);
        foreach($fp_arr as $key => $value){
            for($i=0;$i<$key;$i++){
                echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            }
            echo $value;
        }
    }else{
        echo "No result";
    }
}
?>
```

I know the post is old but the question was fun.
I hope this would help.

Comment: Thank you, hoping it should help me